# iPhone ASIHTTPRequest Asyncroneous Extracting Response from the requestFinished Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have a response that i have returned from the server as a string that needs setting so i can use it in my viewdidload method....

I need the response to be parsed and then displayed in a table view.... I have done this fine using a synchronous request but async would be better for the UI.

below is the method used to grab the response.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
}
```

I need to use the data stored in the "responseString" in my viewdidload method so that the response is parsed and loaded into the table view.

Comment: Why not move the parser to other method than the "viewDidLoad" method and call it with a performSelector:onMainThread / dispatch_async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it in your viewDidLoad. As you've seen, it comes back too late for that.

What you need is to trigger your UITableView to reload itself once you've got your data returned.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    // do something to turn responseString into the data you'll use to 
    // populate your table with data, and then:

    [myTable reloadData];
}
```

So the table will come up empty, and will reload itself once you've got your data to display.

Comment: where will i need to do my request then in order to make it load in the table in order...? thanks

Comment: By any chance... do you no how to set a default value table cell whilst the data is loading the data... as the table is empty when u first load it...

Comment: You want to keep an `NSMutableArray` representing the table data, probably as a named @property. Then in `-numberOfRowsInSection`, you want to return the count of that array. When you first load, you'll initialize that array, and it will have 0 rows, and `numberOfRows` will return 0, which will make the table be a blank space. Then when you reload data, `numberOfRows` will say the number of rows in the array, and it'll do all the rest of its table building business.

Comment: Yer I imagined that was the case, but actually implementing it in my design implementation is a bit different.... I'll have to show you my whole class file for you to understand...

Comment: Well, I'm telling you the canonical way it's done. You deviate from that at your own peril, you know?